# Excel Vlookup #N/A error

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

I need the cell to show blank if the following conditions aren't met but excel is returning an `#N/A` value.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(O14),"",(IF(AND(C14<>"OFF",$B$2="Week 1"),VLOOKUP(B14,Rotation!$D$64:$E$70,2,FALSE),IF(AND(C14<>"OFF",$B$2="Week 2"),VLOOKUP(B14,Rotation!$D$73:$E$79,2,FALSE),IF(AND(C14<>"OFF",$B$2="Week 3"),VLOOKUP(B14,Rotation!$D$82:$E$88,2,FALSE),"")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel would return #N/A with this formula, if you set Week 2 in $B$2, for example, but the value given in B14 is not found in the range `Rotation!$D$73:$E$79`.

You could add a wrapper `IFERROR` to check if the value is not found at all:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(O14),"",(IF(AND(C14<>"OFF",$B$2="Week 1"),VLOOKUP(B14,Rotation!$D$64:$E$70,2,FALSE),IF(AND(C14<>"OFF",$B$2="Week 2"),VLOOKUP(B14,Rotation!$D$73:$E$79,2,FALSE),IF(AND(C14<>"OFF",$B$2="Week 3"),VLOOKUP(B14,Rotation!$D$82:$E$88,2,FALSE),""))))),"")
```

Comment: Or =IFNA(value,value_if_NA)

Comment: @jessiemccartney Welcome! Please consider accepting the answer if it was sufficient, or up-voting if it was useful but insufficient. Cheers!